# How to keep multilevel undefined variable not change when jinja2 render?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am using jinja2 to render my configuration YAML, then ansible uses the YAML to deploy tasks.
Now I meet one problem I can't handle.

I have some a template like this:

```
consultPort: 8500

pool: "{{ system.DCName.aa.bb }}-{{system.poolName}}"

database:
  username: "{{ MSecret('helloworld-prod-aa','username') }}"
  password: "{{ MSecret('helloworld-prod-aa','password') }}"
```

After custom render MSecret, the MSecret function works fine ,but it report `system` undefined,Then I add myself PreservedUndefined to skip Undefined to not change, these Undefined variables will be added into the YAML when ansible deploying

```py
def render(to_reader_text):
    from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader
    env = Environment(loader=BaseLoader,
                      undefined=PreservedUndefined,
                      )
    context = {}
    context['MSecret'] = MSecret
    template = env.from_string(to_reader_text)
    result = template.render(context)
    return result



START = "{{ "
END = " }}"

class PreservedUndefined(Undefined):

    __slots__ = ()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PreservedUndefined, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def __getitem__(self, key):

        return self.__str__(key)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        print "name:" + self._undefined_name
        print "key: " + key
        return self.__str__(key)

    def __str__(self,key):
        if self._undefined_hint is None:

            if self._undefined_obj is missing:
                return u'%s %s.%s %s' % (START, self._undefined_name, key, END)
            return '%s no such element: %s[%r] %s' % (
                START,
                object_type_repr(self._undefined_obj),
                self._undefined_name,
                END
            )
        return u'%s undefined value printed: %s %s' % (self._undefined_hint , START, END)
```

but it only work for only level `system.poolName` not work for `system.DCName.aa.bb`
How to handle `system.DCName.aa.bb`?
I try to  use `ChainableUndefined` from [jinja](https://github.com/pallets/jinja) (maybe not compatiable with Jinja2==2.10.3), but I still can't get the whole name between "{{" and "}}"

```
consultPort: 8500
pool: '{{  no such element: unicode object[''aa'']  }}-{{  system.poolName  }}'
database:
  username: hello
  password: 123
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure an undefined variable always has a default in your template, there is a so called [`default` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default)

```
{{ my_var | default('my_value') }}
{{ my.nested.var | default('some other value') }}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work with nested (possibly undefined) variables. "The default filter is applied against the last lookup, e.g. the .var, so it expects that any variables prior to it are defined." https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/35992#issuecomment-364652115

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko This works perfectly in ansible at least but they might be using a modified version of the filter.... => https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/ffe6e52be12bdc9100b45f7464ab8a3c

Comment: strange, because the link I posted above is specifically for `ansible`. Maybe they changed that later (I didn't check it in `jinja` yet).